# How to insert data in function parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

1. I initialize Datatable on the page:

   ```
   $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable()
   ```

   The problem is that I need to form a parameters (300 lines of code) for this Datatable, so I make an object:
2. ```
   var myfunctions = {

   parametrs: {
               ajax: {
                   type: "POST",
                   data: data, 
                   .....
           }, 

   inittable:  function() {
         a = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable(this.parametrs);
   }
   ```

   The problem is that data has to change depending on user input. So I make a function:
3. ```
    var requestdata =  function() {
       return document.getElementById("daterange").value; 
    };
   ```
4. I change a data in parameters to this function

   ```
   ajax: {
       type: "POST",
       data: requestdata()...
   ```

   However, **when page is first time initialized the function is being called and everything work excellent** however when the code calls this function after user's input, it uses the parameters from initial page initialization, not asking it current (changed!!!) value.

Comment: It is using initial data because when `myfunctions` object is created, the `parameters` object is created with initial data. Instead of saving the data, pass the data to in the function call

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Excellent. It works this way. I have changed  parametrs to function with the return of the same object. And it works now. Thank you for your support. Could you please to form your  comment as an answer for I able to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using initial data because when `myfunctions` object is created, the parameters object is created with initial data.

```
var requestdata =  function() {
    return document.getElementById("daterange").value; 
};

var myfunctions = {

    parametrs: {
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: requestdata(),   // Pass this data as a function parameter
                .....
        }, 

    inittable:  function() {
        a = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable(this.parametrs);
    }
}
```

Instead of saving the data, pass the `data` to the function call.

Comment: Thank you for your support. You have helped me a lot!